# What is the supported way to change version on deploy for Artifactory Maven Jenkins plugin

Tags: maven, jenkins, artifactory, jfrog-cli

I'm using the Maven jfrog plugin: https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/artifactory/#rtmavendeployer-set-maven-deployer

I want to change the version of the artifact on deploy so it has the feature branch name in it.

I tried to run the set version goal. It succeeds but just totally ignores the version

```
rtMavenRun (
        pom: "pom.xml",
        goals: 'versions:set -DnewVersion=1.2.3-SNAPSHOT clean install',
        resolverId: 'resolver-unique-id',
        deployerId: 'deployer-unique-id'
)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the following: You call the goal `versions:set` and the phases `clean` and `install` in one Maven run. Before the first goal runs, Maven has already resolved the version for all goals/phases that are run. Therefore, you change the version in the POM, but as Maven has already read it, you will not be able to see it during this run.

What are possible solutions?

- You can run `versions:set` first and then `clean install` in a separate Maven run.
- You can use the property `${revision}` in the definition of `<version>` and then set this property on the command line.